# How to reference a Docker volume from code?

Tags: ruby, windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am pretty new to Docker, and I am trying to understand how to interact with Docker volumes from code running inside a Docker container.

I have a pretty basic Ruby program that needs to create a file. I want the file that is created by the program to be persisted between runs. I am thinking in order to achieve this I need to use a Docker volume.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app/
RUN bundle install -j 8

VOLUME ["app/data"]

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/app.rb"]
```

Now that I have a volume how would my ruby program write to that location?

If I was to do something in my program like:

```
config_file = "some/directory/config.yml"
File.open(config_file, 'w') { |file| file.write("Hello, from Docker!") }
```

My question is would I reference the volume just like `config_file = "app/data"` and Ruby and Docker will know that the directory "app/data" lives in a volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The files that you are creating/modifying within this path then persist on your host file system. Thus they survive a container lifecycle.

To understand docker volumes in detail take a look [here](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/).

> [...] Docker images
>   are stored as series of read-only layers. When we start a container,
>   Docker takes the read-only image and adds a read-write layer on top.
>   If the running container modifies an existing file, the file is copied
>   out of the underlying read-only layer and into the top-most read-write
>   layer where the changes are applied. The version in the read-write
>   layer hides the underlying file, but does not destroy it.

You can list all volumes known to `docker` by typing `docker volume ls`. If you want to get more information about a  specific volume e.g. the **mountpoint** for your host sytem run the `docker volume inspect VOLUME_NAME` command.

For retrieving only the container specific info about its mounted volume(s) execute:

`docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' CONTAINER_NAME`

I strongly recommend you to use named volumes since I find them easier to identify and manage. Otherwise, the volume name will be an auto-generated cryptic hash.
Mostly I define them within my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  postgres:   
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  # ... other services like web, celery, etc.
```